# Shift rows in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to `shift` values in a `pandas df`. Specifically, `rows` that follow a specific `value`. For the `df` below I want to `shift` the `row` to the left when the above value is `== 'X'`.

```
d = ({
    'A' : ['Foo','','Foo',''],           
    'B' : ['X','Bar','X','Bar'],
    'C' : ['','Y','','Y'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Out:

```
     A    B  C
0  Foo    X   
1       Bar  Y
2  Foo    X   
3       Bar  Y
```

I have tried this:

```
b = ['X']
x = df.B=='X'
df.loc[x, b] = df.loc[x, b].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1), axis=1)
```

Intended Output:

```
     A  B C
0  Foo  X  
1  Bar  Y  
2  Foo  X  
3  Bar  Y
```

Whilst these `strings` are identical my dataset varies. `Foo` will be the same but the `string` that follows `X` will vary. So I can't just select `Bar` and `shift` `row` left. I need something that finds the `row` below `X` and shifts left

Comment: Is `X` only in Column B?

Comment: Yep. It's not duplicated anywhere else @RafaelC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
s = (df == 'X').any(1)
idx_to_change = s[s].index+1
df.loc[idx_to_change,:] = df.loc[idx_to_change].shift(-1,axis=1)

df.fillna('')

    A   B   C
0   Foo X   
1   Bar Y
2   Foo X   
3   Bar Y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
df.replace('',np.nan).apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isnull), 1).fillna('')
Out[538]: 
     A  B C
0  Foo  X  
1  Bar  Y  
2  Foo  X  
3  Bar  Y
```

Comment: Yields a series of lists here?

Comment: @RafaelC what you mean lists here ?

Comment: I get a `pd.Series` of `lists`, like ,`0    [Foo, X, nan]
1    [Bar, Y, nan]
2    [Foo, X, nan]
3      [Foo, W, P]
4    [Bar, Y, nan]
dtype: object`

Comment: @RafaelC idk why you have list here, but on my end it return the dataframe

Comment: @RafaelC maybe restart your jupter

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get rid of empty values, you can use a list comprehension and then feed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
res = pd.DataFrame([list(filter(None, row)) for row in df.values.tolist()],
                   columns=df.columns[:2])

print(res)

     A  B
0  Foo  X
1  Bar  Y
2  Foo  X
3  Bar  Y
```